# Recuperar URI e o Fragment Identifier (#)

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte `url`

```
http://www.site.com/index.php#idDaDiv
```

Gostaria de saber se existe uma variável **$_SERVER[]** ou outro recurso de preferencia em php que retorne apenas

```
index.php#idDadiv
```

Comment: Sim existe: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, para os parametros, e `__FILE__` para o `index.php`, é só concatenares depois

Comment: Minha página é assim: index.php#contatos. Fiz assim: echo __FILE__.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; e não está saindo o #contatos. O que eu faço? os __ não saem aqui nos comentários

Comment: Olá @CarlosRocha a sua última edição da pergunta acaba invalidando a resposta já aceita. Isso é considerado uma [pergunta camaleão](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1682/o-que-fazer-quando-o-o-p-muda-sua-pergunta/1684#1684) e o recomendado nesses casos é reverter a última edição e criar uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Ok! Feito! conforme orientação

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Não é possivel**, o hash/hashtag (*Fragment identifier*) não pode ser recuperado no back-end, independente da linguagem/tecnologia que use, seja PHP, seja asp.net, seja JSP.

Isto ocorre pois o navegador **não envia** a hash junto com **requisição HTTP**, quando digitado no AddressBar.

O hash é usada para interações no front-end, como com CSS, HTML e JavaScript.

### Com HTML

Um exemplo de uso com HTML é para navegar no scroll (rolar até o item desejado):

```css
body {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
section {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    min-height: 140px;
}

.lnks {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="foo">Sessão 1.</section>
<section id="bar">Sessão 2.</section>
<section id="baz">Sessão 3.</section>

<div class="lnks">
    <a href="#foo">vai para foo</a> |
    <a href="#bar">vai para bar</a> |
    <a href="#baz">vai para baz</a>
</div>
```

### Com CSS

Você pode usar para dar destaque em um item com o ID igual a hash (semelhante a situação do Scroll) usando o seletor `:target`:

```css
body {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
section {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background: #fff;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 140px;
    height: 140px;
    display: inline-block;
}

section:target {
   color: #fff;
   font-weight: bold;
   background: #8f8f8f;
}

.lnks {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<section id="foo">Sessão 1.</section>
<section id="bar">Sessão 2.</section>
<section id="baz">Sessão 3.</section>

<div class="lnks">
    <a href="#foo">vai para foo</a> |
    <a href="#bar">vai para bar</a> |
    <a href="#baz">vai para baz</a>
</div>
```

Comment: entendi! Obrigado! A ideia é a de marcar o item de menu com background conforme a página navegada. Mas uma das paginas manda a requisição para uma div específica. Ok

Answer (score 3):

A resposta do @Miguel nos comentários é completa o suficiente para a parte da *query string* (conforme a pergunta).

Sobre retornar a URL sem o HOST (`www.site.com`), podes utilizar apenas `$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`. Esta propriedade lhe retornará toda a URL após o host (`$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]`).

Entretanto, no seu comentário, ficou uma dúvida ainda no ar. Por isso, vejo que é importante uma resposta mais completa.

**Query String**

O seu caso de exemplo foi com a *query string*. Conforme o @Miguel comentou, é possível recuperar através do seguinte código:

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

Para o seu questionamento inicial, a resposta mais adequada é:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Pois, além de retornará tudo que vier após o HOST (`www.site.com`) juntamento com a *query string*.

**Fragment Identifier (#)**

Aqui vem o seu questionamento via comentário. O *[fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)*, anchor, ou, às vezes, hash(tag), é interpretado apenas pelo *browser* (*client-side*) e este não é enviado para o servidor. Utilizando somente PHP, você não será capaz de obter este trecho da URL.

O que normalmente acontece é um pre-processamento da URL e a chamada sendo realizada via JavaScript. É possível recuperar o valor do *fragment* utilizando o seguinte código:

```
window.location.hash
```

Basicamente, deve-se recuperar o *fragment identifier* e adicioná-lo como *query string* em uma requisição **GET** ou adcioná-lo ao *request body* de uma requisição **POST**.

**URL Completa**

Para recuperar a URL completa, basta utilizar o seguinte código:

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Ele irá recuperar URL completa em conjunto com o protocolo. Entretanto, os atributos  `HTTP_HOST` e `REQUEST_URI` pode ser manipulado via client. Não há nada o que possamos fazer a respeito, apenas estarmos cientes que podem ser manipulados.

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php

**Interpretação de URL**

Caso você possua a URL e desejas apenas interpretá-la, existe a função [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
parse_url('http://www.site.com/index.php?param1=123&param2=abril&param3=28#contatos');
```

Saída:

```
array(5) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(12) "www.site.com"
  ["path"]=>
  string(10) "/index.php"
  ["query"]=>
  string(33) "param1=123&param2=abril&param3=28"
  ["fragment"]=>
  string(8) "contatos"
}
```

Comment: Veja só e por favor me perdoe pela pergunta formulada eroneamente. O que tenho é pagina.php#minhaId e não pagina.php?minhaId. Da forma que estou querendo não estou conseguindo pegar todo o nome da pagina com o  #minhaID.

Comment: @CarlosRocha conforme explicado, você só conseguirá se processar a URL via JavaScript. Reformule a pergunta para adequar ao que você quer;

Comment: ok, alterado conforme orientação